# ESP32-CAM camera: SD help

Tags: esp32-cam

I'm struggling with making a simple sketch to take a photo with an ESP32-CAM and save to an SD card.

I have found a bunch of examples that that do what I want, but basically they just take a photo and go to sleep, so every time you reset the unit it runs some code to take a photo, then goes into deep sleep.

The thing is the photos suck, they are green and have no exposure control. I think that it is a known issue that the first photo is always green and the auto gain has not figured out the exposure yet. So because every photo is the first photo after waking up, they all suck.

I tried to move the setup stuff into the loop, and remove the sleep part, but it just straight up doesn't work, and I don't understand enough about coding to even get ChatGPT to help.

I will put the working code below, and then the part I changed. Any help would be great. I thought it would be so simple, I just want to take a photo when I push a button.

```
/*
ESP32 CAM Camera with MicroSD storage
  esp32cam-microsd.ino
  Take picture when button pressed
  Store image on MicroSD card
 
  DroneBot Workshop 2022
  https://dronebotworkshop.com
*/
// Include Required Libraries
 
// Camera libraries
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
#include "driver/rtc_io.h"
 
// MicroSD Libraries
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD_MMC.h"
 
// EEPROM Library
#include "EEPROM.h"
 
// Use 1 byte of EEPROM space
#define EEPROM_SIZE 1
 
// Counter for picture number
unsigned int pictureCount = 0;
 
// Pin definitions for CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22
 
void configESPCamera() {
  // Configure Camera parameters
 
  // Object to store the camera configuration parameters
  camera_config_t config;
 
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; // Choices are YUV422, GRAYSCALE, RGB565, JPEG
 
  // Select lower framesize if the camera doesn't support PSRAM
  if (psramFound()) {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA; // FRAMESIZE_ + QVGA|CIF|VGA|SVGA|XGA|SXGA|UXGA
    config.jpeg_quality = 10; //10-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
 
  // Initialize the Camera
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
 
  // Camera quality adjustments
  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
 
  // BRIGHTNESS (-2 to 2)
  s->set_brightness(s, 0);
  // CONTRAST (-2 to 2)
  s->set_contrast(s, 1);
  // SATURATION (-2 to 2)
  s->set_saturation(s, 0);
  // SPECIAL EFFECTS (0 - No Effect, 1 - Negative, 2 - Grayscale, 3 - Red Tint, 4 - Green Tint, 5 - Blue Tint, 6 - Sepia)
  s->set_special_effect(s, 2);
  // WHITE BALANCE (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_whitebal(s, 1);
  // AWB GAIN (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_awb_gain(s, 1);
  // WB MODES (0 - Auto, 1 - Sunny, 2 - Cloudy, 3 - Office, 4 - Home)
  s->set_wb_mode(s, 0);
  // EXPOSURE CONTROLS (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_exposure_ctrl(s, 1);
  // AEC2 (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_aec2(s, 0);
  // AE LEVELS (-2 to 2)
  s->set_ae_level(s, 0);
  // AEC VALUES (0 to 1200)
  s->set_aec_value(s, 300);
  // GAIN CONTROLS (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_gain_ctrl(s, 1);
  // AGC GAIN (0 to 30)
  s->set_agc_gain(s, 0);
  // GAIN CEILING (0 to 6)
  s->set_gainceiling(s, (gainceiling_t)0);
  // BPC (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_bpc(s, 0);
  // WPC (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_wpc(s, 1);
  // RAW GMA (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_raw_gma(s, 1);
  // LENC (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_lenc(s, 1);
  // HORIZ MIRROR (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_hmirror(s, 0);
  // VERT FLIP (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_vflip(s, 0);
  // DCW (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_dcw(s, 1);
  // COLOR BAR PATTERN (0 = Disable , 1 = Enable)
  s->set_colorbar(s, 0);
}
 
void initMicroSDCard() {
  // Start the MicroSD card
  Serial.println("Mounting MicroSD Card");
  if (!SD_MMC.begin()) {
    Serial.println("MicroSD Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  uint8_t cardType = SD_MMC.cardType();
  if (cardType == CARD_NONE) {
    Serial.println("No MicroSD Card found");
    return;
  }
}
 
void takeNewPhoto(String path) {
  // Take Picture with Camera
  // Setup frame buffer
  camera_fb_t  * fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
 
  if (!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    return;
  }
 
  // Save picture to microSD card
  fs::FS &fs = SD_MMC;
  File file = fs.open(path.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file in write mode");
  }
  else {
    file.write(fb->buf, fb->len); // payload (image), payload length
    Serial.printf("Saved file to path: %s\n", path.c_str());
  }
  // Close the file
  file.close();
 
  // Return the frame buffer back to the driver for reuse
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
}
 
void setup() {
  // Disable brownout detector
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0);
 
  // Start Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  // Initialize the camera
  Serial.print("Initializing the camera module...");
  configESPCamera();
  Serial.println("Camera OK!");
 
  // Initialize the MicroSD
  Serial.print("Initializing the MicroSD card module... ");
  initMicroSDCard();
 
  // initialize EEPROM with predefined size
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  pictureCount = EEPROM.read(0) + 1;
 
  // Path where new picture will be saved in SD Card
  String path = "/image" + String(pictureCount) + ".jpg";
  Serial.printf("Picture file name: %s\n", path.c_str());
 
  // Take and Save Photo
  takeNewPhoto(path);
 
  // Update EEPROM picture number counter
  EEPROM.write(0, pictureCount);
  EEPROM.commit();
 
  // Bind Wakeup to GPIO13 going LOW
  esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO_NUM_13, 0);
 
  Serial.println("Entering sleep mode");
  delay(1000);
 
  // Enter deep sleep mode
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
 
void loop() {
}
```

I changed the set up and loop:

```
void setup() {
  // Disable brownout detector
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0);
 
  // Start Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  // Initialize the camera
  Serial.print("Initializing the camera module...");
  configESPCamera();
  Serial.println("Camera OK!");
 
  // Initialize the MicroSD
  Serial.print("Initializing the MicroSD card module... ");
  initMicroSDCard();
 
  // initialize EEPROM with predefined size
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
  pictureCount = EEPROM.read(0) + 1;
}
 
void loop() {
  // Path where the new picture will be saved on the SD Card
  String path = "/image" + String(pictureCount) + ".jpg";
  Serial.printf("Picture file name: %s\n", path.c_str());

  // Check if GPIO13 is low
  if (digitalRead(GPIO_NUM_13) == LOW) {
    // Take and Save Photo
    takeNewPhoto(path);

    // Update EEPROM picture number counter
    EEPROM.write(0, pictureCount);
    EEPROM.commit();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this [web page](https://www.diyengineers.com/2023/04/13/esp32-cam-complete-guide/), in the section take photo to SD card

```
fb = esp_camera_fb_get(); 
dealy(1000)////
```

***This is key to avoid an issue with the image being very dark and green. If needed adjust total delay time.***

```
fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
```

Hope this helps,

I would suggest take some image buffers first wake the camera up then write the data later to SD card.

Comment: thanks, this helped with the green some of the time, but is way too delayed to be piratical, and does not address the exposure problem.  I really need to keep the ESP on and just trigger the photo capture code with a button.